# Asp.NET 2.0 MemberShip Wizards Password Recovery does not work

Tags: asp.net

I have a web site which I preferred to use a membership wizard. It was working with all its features:

- Sign Up
- Login
- Password Recovery

but these days the password recovery page does not work. I enter my user name but it says the  provided username has not found but it is there!

I tried to code the page I mean not only wizard component but also some hard-code. I mean the following links page...

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d94bdzz2.aspx

but still get the same error. The user name could not found.

Please help me to fix the error.

Regards
BK

Comment: How about posting the membership section of your web.config - does the login still work?

Comment: what do you mean ? please explain.
regards
bk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actuallly it works.
I found the answer. The users that I cannot get the recoveried passwords are the blocked users. In the configuration file if the user enters the password 5 times wrong, the default configuration blocks them. The key is to unblock them.

Regards
BK